# Cannot get property 'ndkVersion' on extra properties extension as it does not exist with... react-native 0.64.0

Tags: android, node.js, reactjs, react-native

***Upgrading from react-native 0.63.4 to 0.64.0***

My steps:

1. `npx react-native run-android` to version 0.64.0 - this step succeeded

2.`npx react-native upgrade` - this step succeeded

3. `npx react-native run-android` - this step failed with following ***2 errors***:

[image]

BTW everything works just fine on iOS simulator.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66769340/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own experience, after migrating 2 very large RN apps (with at least 20 different libraries with linking included) I've concluded that the next solution is the safest but the slowest solution:

So on trying to implement **npx react-native upgrade** I got warnings/errors which tell that upgrade couldn't succeed - that could happen due to files where I had committed some changes.
The solution is to create a **brand new** React Native project (better to create with the same bundle id/name as your current) and to copy/paste the source code from the previous project into the brand new one and after that to link each library one-by-one and make one-by-one build after each library so you keep track of whole process and don't get a large list of errors coming from any of them on app build.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to add the `ndkVersion` to the `android/build.gradle` file in `buildscript.ext`, should look similar to that

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ndkVersion = xxx //<-- Add this
        buildToolsVersion = xxx
        minSdkVersion = xxx
        compileSdkVersion = xxx
        targetSdkVersion = xxx
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Also note that minSdkVersion may also need to be increased, since higher versions of react-native cannot target lower sdk versions. Keep an eye on the log, you'll see which version it needs.

Answer (score 0):

inside `android/buid.gradle`

```
buildscript {
   ext {
      ............

      ............
      ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
   }

   ...........

   ...........
}
```

But make sure which `ndkversion` suits your project.